# Ignore CTRL+C in delay - powershell

Tags: powershell, delay, keypress, powershell-v5.1, powershell-v6.0

Whenever I set a delay in powershell using `Start-Sleep`, e.g:

```
Start-Sleep 10
```

then it does not ignore <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. I mean when I hit that key stroke the delay quits. How can I ignore it in delays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily set `[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput` to `$true`:

```
[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true
Start-Sleep 10  # Ctrl-C will now not abort this sleep.
[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $false
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this:

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(milliseconds)
```

This ignores CTRL-C on delays.